# Switch back to a previous commit using git checkout

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have to rollback master to a previous state without overriding the commits made so far. What is the best way of creating new branches of master and rollback master.

 `/| merge branch A into master (commit id a.into.m)
| | commit (id a2) branch A
| | commit (id 3) branch master
| | commit (id a1) branch A
 \| new branch A commit (id a0)
  | commit 2 master (id m2)
  | commit 1 master (id m1)`

I am trying to create multiple branches of this and reset master to a previous state.
branch new_calculator from commit (id 3)
branch new_form from commit (id a2)
branch rollback_master commit (id m1)

I tried this for all branches

`git checkout m1
git checkout -b rollback_master
git push origin rollback_master`

When I do a pull request of rollback_master into master I don't see any changes. Nothing to merge.
I also tried on the rollback_master branch
`git reset --hard m1` nothing to commit.

Answer (score 3):

In order to revert your master back to an older commit / branch, you require `git reset`.

If you want to reset e.g. a branch `current` to `older_branch`, do

1. Switch to the `current` branch: `git checkout current` (possibly after cloning your repo or stashing uncommitted changes)
2. **Optional** If you want to preserve all commits between `current` and `older_branch`, create a new branch as backup: `git branch backup`
3. Reset the now checked out branch `current` to `older_branch`: `git reset older_branch`

Doing so, your checked out files won't be altered, thus the state you end in will be your `current` branch having been reset to `older_branch`, but your checked out files still being the versions of `current` before the reset.
You probably want to replace your checked out files with the one from `older_branch` as well. For this end, do a `git reset --hard`.

Btw: You can reset to basically anything, it need not be a branch name - you can also use the hash of a commit instead.

However, it's getting more tricky if you deal with remote repositories and you already pushed `current` onto the remote - many remotes won't allow modification of already existing history due to potential conflicts with other contributors. There is another option, though: You can let git create a commit reverting older commits, thus the history won't be altered, but you nevertheless end up with `current` containing the exact state of `older_branch`. This reverting commit can safely pushed into remotes. Check out `git revert`.

Comment: Including the `--hard` flag?

Comment: Then, what do you actually want to achieve? As far as I understand, you did a pull of `rollback_master` into `master` and then tried to reset to `m1` ? Do you want to roll back to `rollback_master` or `m1` ? What does `git status` show?

Comment: I am on master branch now and I want to create a branch `rollback_master` that points to a specific commit in the past. m1 in this example. Then I want to merge that into master. Don't know if pull request will do the trick or some other way

Comment: well, perhaps I formulated my question a bit confusing. What should be the result? you got master, you got rollback_master . both contain files. which file version should be in master? do you want to keep all of the commits between master and rollback_master?

Comment: If you want master to contain the versions of rollback_master, the above should do. if you want to keep the commits in between, checkout master, create a new branch, then do the above. you will end up with master being reset to rollback_master, and as new branch containing the state of master before the reset.

Comment: The goal is to get the files in master to rollback. The files from the old commit should go into master. However, I do not want to lose the work I have committed thus creating the additional two branches to store the work so far.

Comment: afterwards, you can tweak your history of you want to. e.g. you could then checkout master, then pull your new branch in, possibly with `git pull backup_master --no-ff` ..  but it depends all in what you want to end up with...

Comment: ah, sorry, did not read your reply in time... anyhow, would the suggestions in my two previous comments work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206021/discussion-between-kal-and-michael-beer).

Comment: As it turned out, my original answer did not really solve the question. However, Since the answer already got 2 upvotes, there seem to be people who considered it helpful. Therefore, I decided to add some infos that could help further and keep the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Git isn't really about *branches*.  It's really about *commits*.  Branch names are just labels we (and Git) use to *find* commits.

The log output you drew:

```
 /| merge branch A into master (commit id a.into.m)
| | commit (id a2) branch A
| | commit (id 3) branch master
| | commit (id a1) branch A
 \| new branch A commit (id a0)
  | commit 2 master (id m2)
  | commit 1 master (id m1)
```

is kind of close to the ASCII-art graphs that `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` draws, but lacks the little asterisks that it uses to mark commits:

```
*   4291fbf Merge dotfiles installer
|\  
| * 4f5b84b dotfiles: add --tar option
| * 8a45ff6 dotfiles: refuse to install over special files
| * e750c89 dotfiles: reshuffle work-to-do code
| * 36aa02c dotfiles: s/--install-to/--homedir/
| * 93c597c dotfiles: simplify FileInfo
| * 4771f69 dotfiles: manipulate home dir .foorc etc
|/  
* 6c9a43a add prototype Dot-files
```

Note that each commit also has a unique hash ID (here they've been shortened).  These hash IDs are the real names of the commits.

Branch *names* merely act as *pointers*, pointing to these commits.  I like to draw these things sideways, rather than vertically, for StackOverflow postings.  I also like to give them single uppercase letters, instead of big ugly hash IDs.  The result is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branch1
            \
             I--J   <-- branch2
```

The idea here is that each branch name *points to* one commit.  The commits themselves also point (backwards) one step, so that `J` points to `I`, `I` points to `H`, `H` points to `G`, and so on.

The commits that are "on" a branch in Git are those you can get to by starting with the branch name, following its arrow to its commit, and then working backwards from that commit.  It's therefore in some sense better to say that these commits are *contained in* the branch, because commits up through `H` are on—or contained in—*both* branches, while commits `I` and `J` are currently contained only `branch2`.

Now, the things to know about these commits and branch names include:

- No commit can ever be changed.  At most, you can take some existing commit and copy it to a new-and-improved version, which will get a new and different hash ID.
- As we just said, the set of commits contained in some branch are obtained by starting where the branch points, and then walking from commit to commit, backwards, one step at a time.  The names themselves just contain the commit hash ID of whatever commit we say should be the *last* commit in the branch.
- Branch names therefore *move*.  Their normal progression is forwards: we start with some set of commits, like the ones above, and then add a new commit.  For instance, if we `git checkout branch1`, we get commit `H`.  If we make a new commit, it gets a new ID, which we'll call `K` (`I` and `J` are in use):

  ```
  ...--F--G--H---K   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
              \
               I--J   <-- branch2
  ```

  (We can use the word `HEAD`, attaching it to some branch like this, to remember which branch we're on.)
- The normal motion, as we just saw, is to add-on.  Let's merge `branch2` into `branch1`.  Without worrying about how Git accomplishes this, let's draw the result:

  ```
  ...--F--G--H---K--L   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
              \    /
               I--J   <-- branch2
  ```

  New commit `L` is a *merge commit*, which is one with two parents (or more than two, but we won't see that here).

#### Getting back to your question

Since branch names just point to specific commits, we can add more names and/or force names to move in directions they normally don't:

```
 ...--F--G--H---K--L   <-- branch1 (HEAD), master
             \    /
              I--J   <-- branch2
```

Let's force the name `master` to point to commit `K` instead of `L`:

```
$ git branch -f master <hash-of-K>
```

and draw the result:

```
               K     <-- master
              / \_
             /    \
 ...--F--G--H------L   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
             \    /
              I--J   <-- branch2
```

Nothing has actually *changed* in terms of the commits, but the labels have moved.

But `master` moved in the "wrong" direction.  If we connect our Git to some other Git, and *their* `master` points to commit `L`, and we ask them to move their master to point to commit `K` like ours does, they'll generally say *no*.  The reason they will say no is that this branch label move is in the wrong direction.  The Git term for this is that it is not a *fast-forward*.

We can use `git push --force` to *command* them to move their `master` like this.  They may or may not obey.  Other clones of our or their repository may also have a `master` that points "ahead of" commit `K`, e.g., to `L`, and we'll have to convince *them* to move the same way.

So:

> I am trying to create multiple branches of this and reset master to a previous state. branch new_calculator from commit (id 3) branch new_form from commit (id a2) branch rollback_master commit (id m1)

You *can* do this, in your own Git repository, where you control everything.  Just change your labels around and make new labels as needed.  All the existing commits stay put; only the *labels* move.  See [Michael Beer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59757193/1256452) for more details on how to do this (with `git reset` and/or `git branch -f`).

You won't necessarily be able to change *anyone else's* Git repository.  That includes any copy of your own Git repository that you put on GitHub.  That's GitHub's repository, after all, not yours: they're just letting you control it, and it's up to them to decide how much control to give you.

If you own it so that GitHub will give you *full* control, and no one else has Git repositories that you need to worry about, you can `git push --force` your updates to your GitHub repository (aka "GitHub's repository that they're holding for you").

If *not*, though, what you generally should do is add *new* commits to the repository, so that the new commits extend existing chains of commits in this "moving forward" manner.  The new commits simply record the new state of things as well.  All Gits everywhere understand the concept of moving forward, and the new commits refer back to the existing commits, so all the previous committed files are still there in their previously-committed versions.

> When I do a pull request of rollback_master into master ...

Pull requests aren't part of Git.  They're an extension offered by services like GitHub.

When you make a pull request, you attach a label—the actual label is up to the service—to some commit in some repository that exists on the server.  That commit has some hash ID, as all commits do.  Then, the server delivers the pull request (complete with internal attached label) to whoever they're having manage *other* repository—the one you forked from.  (The server has recorded that repository somewhere.  In some cases, you choose as the "other" repository, this repository; then the someone is whoever owns this repository.)  That person gets a user interface that allows them to:

- run a slightly modified `git merge` on the GitHub server, or
- run a slightly modified `git rebase` on the GitHub server, or
- run a slightly modified `git merge --squash` on the GitHub server.

None of these steps include a `git push --force` "move label in arbitrary manner" operation.  All of them either generally or specifically create a *new* commit that adds on to existing commits.  So all operations done through pull requests are necessarily very unlike the kind of `git push --force` that moves a label backwards.

To put it another way, if you go down that road, "you can't get there from here". :-)